# ExcelNewbie: Matching cell information across worksheets

Tags: excel

Please forgive me if this is simple...I am not an Excel expert and this is causing my nose to bleed(!)

Firstly I am using Excel 365.

I am working on a Bonus Calculator Sheet and the system is VERY complex, but I have reduced it to a two column table.

Column A is the company success "number" and column B is the % bonus it draws. This is all on worksheet B.
Worksheet A contains salary stuff and the company success number sits at the top and is not changed. What I need to do in pseudocode is:

Take value from Sheet A Cell A1
Find match in Sheet B Column A.
Return value next to it in Column B to Sheet A somewhere.

My life is mainly spent in the world of Python and this looks SO simple - but any help you experts could offer would just make my day rosier...if anyone can help I will give my two dogs a biscuit to show the love(!)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty simple.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,SheetB!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using index match formula

```
=INDEX(SheetB!B:B,MATCH(A1,SheetB!A:A,0))
```

Where A1 is the value that you want to lookup in SheetB in range A:A.